# Fetching spreadsheet data does not update on client when new values are inserted in spreadsheet

Tags: node.js, express, google-sheets-api

I'm using google-spreadsheet npm package and express to retrieve all rows from my spreadsheet.
on my client side i'm using a fetch and log all the rows in my console.

I am using a simple spreadsheet with name/surnames.
Whenever I try to manually add some new names in the rows in my spreadsheet i'd have to restart my server to see the data being fetched again with the changed rows.
using an interval to call the api again after changing my sheet still doesn't update the data on my client.

Is there a way to automatically update the data getting fetched everytime I change something in the sheet manually without restarting the server everytime?

index.js :

```
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet')
const creds = require('./credentials.json')
const express = require('express')
app = express()

app.use(express.static('public'));


app.listen(3000, console.log('listening at http://localhost:3000/'))
var doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('my spreadsheet ID');

// Authenticate with the Google Spreadsheets API.
doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds, function (err) {

  // Get all of the rows from the spreadsheet.
  doc.getRows(1,  (err, rows) => {
    console.log(rows);
    app.get('/sheet', (req,res) =>{res.send(rows)})
  });
});
```

html:

````
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
</body>

<script >
async function FetchFromSheet()
    {
        const response= await fetch('/sheet')
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
    }

    setInterval(() => {
        FetchFromSheet()
    }, 10000);
    </script>

</html>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google-spreadsheet npm package lets you make an API call to Google Sheets to fetch the latest version of the spreadsheet data. API calls are made based on your definition, and by default, are not meant to track changes on the sheet itself. This is why your data updates only when you restart your server, as you call your API only once (on start)

What you're looking for, is the [Google Sheets webhook](https://blog.runscope.com/posts/tutorial-capturing-webhooks-with-google-sheets) which can send a POST request to a route that you specify, on the sheet being changed. You can essentially use this webhook request's receipt as a "prompt" to refresh your Google Sheets data.

Comment: Thank you! It took me a while to figure it out but I managed to get it working. webhooks saves the day!

Comment: @SuRots were you able to use this webhook? I'm struggling with it. There seems to be some differences from the version in the article from what is being used now on Google Spreadsheets. Can't find the publish > deploy as an web app option